# How to add the diagnostics extension on cloud service using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, azure-resource-manager

I would like to know how we need to define the resource in ARM template for enabling the Diagnostics extension on Cloud service deployed. In the examples that i came across, i could see it only for Virtual Machines with IaasDiagnostics. But i couldnt find anything on enabling the diagnostics on cloud service(PaaSDiagnostics).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

ARM template is used to deploy and provision all of the resources for your application in a single, coordinated operation, which is only available in Azure Resource Manager while **Cloud Service** is in Azure Service Manager, so you could not use cloud service in ARM template.

You could look at [Create a Windows Virtual machine with monitoring and diagnostics using Azure Resource Manager Template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-diagnostics-template/) to enable diagnostics in ARM template.